# symfony 2: using asset for image path in css

Tags: php, css, symfony

I'm a newbie to both php and symfony. I have been using successfully the following syntax for including css and scripts to my page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

Now, I have a css that refers to an image

```
.menu{
 background: url(../img/mobile.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

The image is not found. I think this is because I cannot use the `asset()` syntax here.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Where exactly do you use the `asset()`? Can you post that code?

Comment: yes sorry, I've edited my post.But the question is how do I do that in a css file.

Answer (score 0):

look at the web folder and if the image exist or not because you don't use asset in css just in twig

did you generate the images with assets:install web so that the images exist in the web folder

Comment: the image is in the web/img folder. I did not generate anything (I don't even know what assets:install is. I just dropped the img folder into the web folder. Should that not be enough ?

Comment: no it's not because the img folder sould be in
\web\bundles\nameofyourbundle exemple
\web\bundles\AcmeExemple

Answer (score 0):

The css rewrite filter can solve this situation:

```
{% stylesheets "css/bootstrap.css" filter="cssrewrite" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/YOUR_BUNDLE_NAME/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

Where `YOUR_BUNDLE_NAME` is ex. `testbundle`

Make sure you put `bootstrap.css` file into `/TestBundle/Resources/public/css` directory.

Execute command:

```
php app/console assets:install
```

This command will 'hard copy' all files in public folder to web folder where it will be available.

Your path to css fiels will be now `bundles/testbundle/css/bootstrap.css`